# CSS Background color section but not page

Tags: html, css

I have section like this:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpDgu.png)

And I want section like this:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv4qG.jpg)

When I change css of that section, I get results like on image 1.
The problems are that sides, it leaves it white because that is background color of the whole page, but I don't want to change bg of the whole page.

I want the results like on the image2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Answer (score -1):

in this case you don't have to set the background colour of whole(parent ) just change the background colour of chlild  or child html element that you are using..its simple

### don't do this

```
<div style="background-color:#fff">
</div>
```

### do this

```
<div>
<span style="color:#fff">name</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You've managed to introduce both CSS and HTML syntax errors in that tiny example.

Comment: After fixing the syntax errors, you appear to be (a) Taking the problem described in the question and are making it *more extreme* instead of fixing it and (b) Are changing the wrong property

Comment: Thank you for replaying, but it's not the solution.
That side that keeps to be white is a part of html, body elements, that's the problem.